# Android URI to Cursor

Tags: android

if I have convert URI of file path in sdcard to Cursor in android

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(XXX, null, null, null, null);
if(null != cursor)
{
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor);
    setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);
}
```

What can I put instead of XXX ...

```
private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
    super(context, layout, c, new String[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},
    new int[] { R.id.displayname, R.id.title, R.id.duration });
    }
}
```

can any one help me please

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should use `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` for XXX,

```
String[] projection = {    
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
};
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection, // Which columns to return

    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", // Return all rows
    new String[] {"%/path/to/my/files/%"},

    // or: 
    // MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
    // new String[] { filePath }, 

    null);
```

Comment: exception when I use this: java.lang.IllegalArgumentExeeption:column 'duration' does not exis

Comment: If that is for audio, then use: MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. Replace all  `MediaStore.Images` with `MediaStore.Audio`. If thats is for Vide then you have `MediaStore.Video....`

Comment: I use this:
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "=? ", // Return all rows
        new String[] {"/mnt/sdcard/sound/"}, null);

but it return null why???!!!!

Comment: no idea, I tested this code (updated answer for Audio) on my 2.3.3 Sony XPeria and it works.

Comment: add any permission??!!